# Rails getting routes name in Route.rb with controller actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm a real beginner of rails.

Can I get multiple routes from one controller + many actions?

For example,

```
resources :something
```

get "something#index", "something#show", "something#update"...etc.

I'm just curious if there is a command to get route name from the actions.

For example, in a controller named "pledges",

```
class PledgesController < ApplicationController
    def home
    end

    def abc
    end

    def defg
    end

    def hijk
    end
end
```

Can any commands get "pledges#home", "pledges#abc", "pledges#defg","pledges#hijk" ?

Comment: [`resources`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb#L1440) creates seven different routes corresponding to the CRUD operations because is as it's defined, it doesn't seem to be defined to work with "custom" controller actions. If not resources, then I think there's nothing similar to do that.

Comment: Are you asking how to define custom (non-RESTful) routes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add custom, "non-RESTful" routes to a resource, you could do the following:

```
resources :pledges do
  collection do
    get :foo
  end

  member do
    put :bar
  end
end
```

`collection`-defined routes will produce results against `Pledge` as a whole – think the `index` route.

`member`-defined routes will produce results against an *instance* of `Pledge` – think the `show` route.

This would produce the following routes for you:

```
foo_pledges  GET       /pledges/foo(.:format          pledges#foo
bar_pledge   PUT       /pledges/:id/bar(.:format)     pledges#bar
pledges      GET       /pledges(.:format)             pledges#index
             POST      /pledges(.:format)             pledges#create
new_pledge   GET       /pledges/new(.:format)         pledges#new
edit_pledge  GET       /pledges/:id/edit(.:format)    pledges#edit
pledge       GET       /pledges/:id(.:format)         pledges#show
             PATCH     /pledges/:id(.:format)         pledges#update
             PUT       /pledges/:id(.:format)         pledges#update
             DELETE    /pledges/:id(.:format)         pledges#destroy
```

Comment: Okay, I was curious about If I can make routes automatically based on the name of actions in controller. But anyway thanks for your answer :)

Comment: Is it?! Thank you!!

Comment: Definitely. You could have tons of methods in your controllers that you don't want/need routes for.

Comment: I'd encourage you to read up on a software design principle called "separation of concerns". [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) will explain the basics of the concept and [this](http://aspiringcraftsman.com/2008/01/03/art-of-separation-of-concerns/) is a pretty solid blog post about it if you want to dive a little deeper. :-D

Answer (score 0):

You will have to define all of the custom actions, if there are not restful (*but I would highly recommend that you follow the rest conventions*). For example:

```
get  'pledges' => 'abc'
post 'pledges' => 'defg'
put  'pledges' => 'hijk
```